# Calculate cutoff frequency of a digital IIR filter

Tags: digital-filter

I have an ADC with 1 kS/s and would like to append a digital anti-aliasing filter to it as I have to downsample the data to 10 Hz.

As it's on an FPGA and I don't have any multipliers, I thought the easiest way would be a recursive averaging IIR filter:

$$ y = \alpha x[n] + (1-\alpha)y[n-1]$$

But how can I calculate the cutoff frequency of such a filter depending on \$\alpha\$ and \$f_s\$?

Comment: Makes me wonder where you learned how to make an IIR filter, if they didn't spend one line explaining that relationship. It's hardly useful without knowing the frequency.

Comment: It's been a decade since then... people forget :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With you needing an anti-alias filter for 1/100 of the bandwidth, I'd say that both your single-pole IIR (exponentially weighted moving average) and actual moving averages are out of the question; you'd need suppression in 99% of your band sufficiently high enough to mitigate aliases.

Simultaneously, you need a filter with a steep transition between pass- and stopband, relative to the original Nyquist rate.

Neither filter approaches will achieve such a steepness.

Higher-order CICs can achieve sufficient suppression through offering a very steep (potentiated sinc) impulse response, and their use in decimators (like your 100-fold decimation) is very popular due to the elegant nature of the math: you can drag the decimation stage between the integrators and the differentiators, like

```
-1 kHz-->(+)------·--->[↓100]---·------(+)---10 Hz->
          ^       |             |       ^
          --[z⁻¹]--             --[z⁻ⁿ]--
```

As you can see: extremely low component effort!

In all honesty, though: You're building a massively decimating filter, at a sample rate that is ridiculously low for FPGAs, aiming for a sampling rate that's even lower.

Do yourself a favor. Calculate a proper 1/100-band FIR filter. At these rates, you really need but a single multiplier that you use for all coefficients. And even then it doesn't need to be a fast one. That way, you gain significantly more freedom in designing your filter response.

**Found it**: You should *really* read [this](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1337.php) article of Richard Lyons, whom you can also work with over on our [Signal Processing StackExchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) sister site.

Answer (score 5):

What you propose is often called an "exponentially weighted moving average", and armed with that term, you can probably find a formula ([wikipedia discusses this in some way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average)).

Generally, what you propose doesn't even work without a multiplier (how do you multiply with \$\alpha\$ and \$1-\alpha\$ without a multiplier– they can't both be a power of two at the same time?), so I doubt it's actually a solution to your problem.

(An *actual* moving average would work – just add up a window of \$N\$ input items, tada, convolution with a rectangle corresponds to a sinc in spectrum of \$\frac1N\$ width. But that's not a great filter, honestly, because of the sidelobes.)

What you will be interested in is *Cascaded Integrator-Comb* filters (CICs), which

1. do actually not require any multipliers, because all the coefficients are 1 or 0,
2. are actually FIR although having feedback structure, and
3. have an easy to calculate frequency response that's probably closer to what you had in mind when you said "low-pass filter".

Comment: Well I can subtract, so if I chose \$\alpha\$ as e.g. 0.03 I'd then shift everything by 5 bits and subtract 1. Of course there are some limitations...
Regarding your point 3, I think I actually need an anti-aliasing filter

Comment: but an anti-aliasing filter is on the analog side of an ADC, otherwise it's too late. (Unless you want to resample the digital signal to a lower rate, but I'd guess you would've mentioned that)

Comment: No that's actually the case yes, I need to downsample by factor 100

Comment: ... Well, then edit your question to include that crucial info, @po.pe. This is what you need your filter for – so that defines what kind of filter you need.

Comment: Information added... I'll have a dive into CIC filters

Answer (score 5):

> *I thought the easiest way would be a recursive averaging IIR filter*

Your equation represents a simple low-pass, first-order filter hence, \$\alpha\$ equals: -

$$\dfrac{t_{SAMPLE}}{CR}$$

Where CR is the equivalent CR time for a resistor-capacitor low-pass filter. So, with 1 kHz sampling and a required frequency cut-off (\$F_C\$) of (say) 10 Hz you'd calculate CR as follows: -

$$F_C = \dfrac{1}{2\pi RC}$$

For 10 Hz, CR therefore equals 0.015915 and T/CR = 0.06283.

---

### Linear Simulation with VIN at 1 volt peak and 10 Hz

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Discretely sampled at 1 kHz (prior to feeding into 1st summing block):

[image]

### 10th order, 10 Hz low pass filter (fairly Butterworthesque):

[image]

AC response: -

[image]

Response with 10 Hz input (down 3 dB): -

[image]

Response with 13 Hz input (down 22 dB): -

[image]

Response with 16 Hz input (down 39.5 dB): -

[image]

Response with 20 Hz input (down 58.7 dB): -

[image]

Comment: If I need higher order, would I just cascade them?

Comment: Cascading them is the usual way but you can cascade in ways that give an improved frequency response. Maybe take a look at [this old document](http://www.jamesoakwood.co.uk/Digital%20filter%20design%20for%20Analogue%20engineers.pdf?LMCL=It7Tc1). It shows you how to cascade in a way that gives better performance around the cut-off frequency.

Answer (score 4):

Besides what the others have said, your difference equation leads to this transfer function:

$$H(z)=\frac{\alpha}{1-(1-\alpha)z^{-1}}$$

and evaluating it is done by substituting \$z^{-1}=e^{-j\Omega_p}\$:

$$H(\Omega_p)=\frac{\alpha}{1-(1-\alpha)e^{-j\Omega_p}}$$

If you consider the corner frequency to be the -3dB point, then this results back in this difference equation, followed by solving for the exact (sampled) frequency, \$\Omega_p=\pi\frac{f_p}{f_0}\$:

$$\begin{align}
\left|H(\Omega_{-3\mathrm{dB}})\right|^2=\frac12&=\left|\frac{\alpha}{1-(1-\alpha)(\cos\Omega_p-j\sin\Omega_p)}\right|^2 \\
\Rightarrow 2\alpha^2&=\left[1-(1-\alpha)\cos\Omega_p\right]^2+\left[(1-\alpha)\sin\Omega_p\right]^2 \\
&=(\alpha^2-2\alpha+1)(\cos^2\Omega_p+\sin^2\Omega_p)+2(\alpha-1)\cos\Omega_p+1 \\
&=2(\alpha-1)\cos\Omega_p+\alpha^2-2\alpha+2 \\
\Rightarrow \Omega_p&
=\arccos{\frac{\alpha^2+2\alpha-2}{2(\alpha-1)}}
\end{align}$$

To verify, let's say \$\alpha=0.45\$, then

$$\Omega_p=0.6165 \\
|H(0.6165)|=\left|\frac{0.45}{1-0.55e^{-j0.6165}}\right|=0.7071$$

A picture might be worth a thousand words, so here's a quick check with LTspice, two versions of it:

[image: test]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a 1st order IIR Lowpass (also known as an exponential average) in C, using only shifts and no multiply:

```
//1st-order IIR lowpass
//2^(-SHIFT) = 1 - e^(-2*pi * Fc/Fs)
//Fc = Fs * (-ln(1 - 2^(-SHIFT)) / (2*pi))
//Fs = sample rate, Fc = -3dB cutoff frequency

void IIR_lowpass_1(int in, *out, SHIFT)
{
    *out -= (*out >> SHIFT);
    *out += (  in >> SHIFT);
}
```

It's become a standard block of code that I've used in a bunch of different projects now.  You can do the math to see that this sequential operation has the exact same effect as the canonical version.
It must be atomic though - no task switching in the middle of it!

I'll leave it to the reader, both to optimize it as needed, and to translate it from a microcontroller to an FPGA.  My point is simply that it *can* be done without a multiply.

---

For higher orders, you can cascade a bunch of 1st orders:

```
void IIR_lowpass_2(int in, *mid, *out, SHIFT)
{
    IIR_lowpass_1(  in, *mid, SHIFT);
    IIR_lowpass_1(*mid, *out, SHIFT);
}

void IIR_lowpass_3(int in, *mid1, *mid2, *out, SHIFT)
{
    IIR_lowpass_1(   in, *mid1, SHIFT);
    IIR_lowpass_1(*mid1, *mid2, SHIFT);
    IIR_lowpass_1(*mid2,  *out, SHIFT);
}
```

Etc.

`out` and `mid_` must each have their own dedicated storage.

Comment: HI AaronD, um, the question is about an FPGA implementation, not a software implementation!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I understood the FPGA part to only justify the requirement of "no multiply".  The question is *really* about "no multiply" and "calculating the cutoff", both of which I *have* covered.

Comment: true! I didn't mean to put your answer down here.